# Can't do set based nested updates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, nested

I'm trying to be a good DB developer and avoid using a loop or a cursor here, but I'm not sure this can be done.

I have rows in table A that represent pointers to different processing queues. In table B I have data that needs to be processed. The rows in table A contain a `datetime` column called `LastUsed` which is used to indicate when a processing queue was last used to process data. This column is updated using `GETUTCDATE()` each time a row from table B is assigned to a particular queue... and that the crux of my round-robin queue problem.

Let's say table B has 50 data rows in it, and table A has 5 queue rows. In a set based way, I need to assign queue IDs from table A to all 50 rows in table B using an `UPDATE` and end up with something like the following;

**TABLE B**

```
data record 1 - queue 1 
data record 2 - queue 2 
data record 3 - queue 3
data record 4 - queue 4
data record 5 - queue 5
data record 6 - queue 1
data record 7 - queue 2
data record 8 - queue 3
etc...
```

Basically, the `LastUsed` column for each queue row in table A must be updated each time the queue column in a data row in table B is updated so the next data row will receive the "new" oldest queue row from table A.

I've tried creating a UDF but I can't use the `UPDATE` command from inside a UDF. I've also tried a nested `UPDATE` statement for table A using the `OUTPUT` clause in hopes of wrapping it inside another `UPDATE` statement for table B, but SQL Server informs me I cannot nest updates like that.

Am I stuck here? Do I ***have*** to use a cursor or loop?

Comment: Do you really care about this oldest/newest?  You are inserting 50 objects into 5 queues.  As far as i can tell you are doing it in random order from the data records.  For 45 of those inserts all of your queue tables will be within a millisecond of equal age.  So, does that millisecond Actually, Really matter?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use two separate statements, one for each table. Wrap then in a transaction so you get atomicity. Maybe raise the isolation level to the appropriate level.

You can achieve round-robin assignment using the `ROW_NUMBER` function and taking it modulo the number of queues.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRAN

create table tmp_queue (age datetime, id int)
go

insert into tmp_queue values(getutcdate(), 1)
insert into tmp_queue values(getutcdate(), 2)
insert into tmp_queue values(getutcdate(), 3)
insert into tmp_queue values(getutcdate(), 4)
insert into tmp_queue values(getutcdate(), 5)
go

create table tmp_data (id int, data varchar(15))
go

insert into tmp_data values(1, 'foo')
insert into tmp_data values(2, 'foo')
insert into tmp_data values(3, 'foo')
insert into tmp_data values(4, 'foo')
insert into tmp_data values(5, 'foo')
insert into tmp_data values(6, 'foo')
insert into tmp_data values(7, 'foo')
insert into tmp_data values(8, 'foo')
insert into tmp_data values(9, 'foo')
insert into tmp_data values(10, 'foo')
insert into tmp_data values(11, 'foo')
insert into tmp_data values(12, 'foo')
insert into tmp_data values(13, 'foo')
insert into tmp_data values(14, 'foo')
insert into tmp_data values(15, 'foo')
go

create table tmp_queued_data (queue_id int, data_id int, inserted datetime)
go

insert into tmp_queued_data (queue_id, data_id, inserted)
select (RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY id /6 ORDER BY id asc )) as queue_for_me, id, getutcdate()
from tmp_data



update tmp_queue 
set age = (select MAX(inserted)
            from tmp_queued_data
            where queue_id = tmp_queue.id)

select * from tmp_queued_data
select * from tmp_queue


ROLLBACK
```

This is assuming you don't care about that millisecond